# Cannot find symbol in same Package

Tags: java, compilation, package, symbols

I have two public classes **Employee** and **Salary** in the **same package**. Employee is the parent class and Salary is the child class.
When I compile the Employee class using the "**-d**" flag the code compiles fine and also generates the appropriate directory structure as per the package name.
However when I try to compile the Salary class it gives me the following error:

```
Salary.java:2: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Employee
public class Salary extends Employee{

1 error
```

Here is my code:
 **Employee.java**

```
package com.alok.Manage;

public class Employee{
  private int eno;
  private String name;

  Employee()
  {
      this(0,"");

  }
  Employee(int n,String nm)
  {
     this.eno=n;
     this.name=nm;
  }

  public int getEno()
  {
     return this.eno;
  }
  public String getName()
  {
     return this.name;
  }
}
```

**Salary.java**

```
package com.alok.Manage;
public class Salary extends Employee{

   private int Salary;

   public int getSal()
   {
     return this.Salary;
   }

   public void setsal(int s)
   {
     this.Salary=s;
   }
}
```

If I remove the package declaration from both the files then it compiles without any errors.

Comment: Your `private int Salary` should really be lowercase "s", `salary`... http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: @mjr : I don't think that causes any issues.

Comment: @PraneethNilangaPeiris It's not related to the questioner's issue, but it's definitely a bad idea to use an uppercase S because it's very confusing.

Comment: I'm new to java and don't really know the conventions as of now......i'll start picking up pretty soon......thanks for the info. But I don't think that's causing any problem.

Comment: I don't get an error why I try this.  Are you sure your files are in the correct directories/folders, and that you're in the correct directory when you're compiling?

Comment: Are your source files located in the appropriate directory structure  `com\alok\Manage`? While talking about naming conventions here: consider using only lower case letters for packages. Also: if you are on linux, make sure the case of the directories and the case of the package declaration matches.

Comment: @ajb both my java files are in the same directories

Comment: @ajb : Yes, that is true.. :)

Comment: Perhaps you should start over and try compiling without the `-d` flag.  That could be causing a problem.  I put both `.java` files in `...mydirectory\com\alok\Manage`.  Then, **when in mydirectory**, I typed `javac com\alok\Manage\Employee.java` and `javac com\alok\Manage\Salary.java`.  Worked fine.  This is on Windows from a Command Prompt window.

Comment: I'm using linux. The source files are in the directory "java". I've made another directory "test" in it. I used javac -d test Employee.java to compile the first file. It compiled ok and the directories and class file were created in the "test" directory. But the same thing doesn't work for the Salary class

Comment: The convention is to create subdirectories that match the package name, i.e. `com/alok/Manage`, and put the sources in that package there.  That's how `javac` works normally.  There may be ways to put the sources in a different directory and cajole `javac` into finding everything there, but it looks like it's going to fight you.  So I think I'd just do things the standard way.  Seems easiest.  (And on Linux you can use `ln -s` to have the files in two directories at once, if that suits you.)

Comment: Issue is resolved.....I didn't knew about using the -cp option when compiling the Salary.java file. **javac -d test -cp ./test Salary.java**   did the trick......Thanks everyone  for your inputs.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are not using any IDE, Use -cp option while compiling Salary to specify where to find the Employee class file.

Comment: do i need to specify the whole path of the Employee class file using the -cp option or just upto the "test" directory???

Comment: specify the folder path where Employee class file is present.

Comment: It worked!!!! I used  javac -d test -cp /test Salary.java Thanks for your help :)